# Cssselect выбор данных из meta

Tags: python, cssselect

Имеется html:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Оборудование для бассейна - купить в интернет-магазине Aquapolis">
<meta property="og:description" content="Оборудование для бассейна - купить в интернет-магазине Aquapolis">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://aquapolis.ru/oborudovanie-dlja-bassejna.html">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://aquapolis.ru/media/opengraph/website/frontend/ultimo/default/images/logo.gif">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
```

Необходимо вытащить ссылку (meta  у которой og:url)
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и попыток:

```
url = html.cssselect('meta[property="og:url"]')[0].get("content")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это сделать вот так с помощью `BeautifulSoup`:

```
url = soup.find("meta",  property="org:url")
print(url["content"] if url else "No meta url given")
```

Находите `org:url` и вытаскиваете `content`.

Comment: Но я же просил с помощью cssselect. К тому же я использую Lxml, без BS4

Comment: Че реально никто не знает как сделать средствами Lxml? Ведь Beautiful Soup это всего лишь обертка над Lxml